# Arduino 'for' error

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I have made a program for my Arduino which will sort an array of fifty random numbers in ascending or descending order, I think I have got it all right, but when I run it I get an error message "expected unqualified-id before 'for' ".

```
int array [50];
int i = 0;

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600); // Load Serial Port
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.println ("Position " + array[i]);
  delay (2000);

}

for (i <= 50) {      <-----*Here is where the error highlights*--->
  int n = random (251); // Random number from 0 to 250
  array[i] = n;
  i++;
}

// Bubble sort function
void sort (int a[], int size) {
    for(int i=0; i<(size-1); i++) {
        for(int o=0; o<(size-(i+1)); o++) {
                if(a[o] > a[o+1]) {
                    int t = a[o];
                    a[o] = a[o+1];
                    a[o+1] = t;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I have annotated where the error is shown. I need to get past this to test my code, I have no clue on how to fix it!

Comment: The code needs to be in a function.

Comment: That is not the correct syntax for a for-loop. Replace the `for` with `while` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You have written it wrong. There is pseudocode of for loop:

```
for(datatype variableName = initialValue; condition; operation){
 //your in loop code
}
//Code wich will be executed after end of for loop above
```

In your case it will look like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 50 ; i++){
    int n = random (251); // Random number from 0 to 250
    array[i] = n;
}
```

- Another thing is, that you are trying to iterate the array. The first index is 0. It means the **last index is 49 not 50**. If you try to access 50th index it will crash your program.
- Last thing is, that the for loop we are talking about is out of any method. It will never be executed.

Comment: Hello, I have implemented the changes you have suggested however, I am still facing the same error. I may have missed telling you that the highest and the lowest numbers in the array should be displayed on eight L.E.Ds.

Comment: If you getting this error it means that you still have for loop outside function body.

Comment: please check this post, it is the bigger picture of the problem. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49904298/arduino-bubble-sort-ascending-descending-order)

Answer (score 0):

The for loop requires three parts to its parameters:

1. A variable to count iterations
2. A condition that must be true to continure
3. A increment factor

Each part should be separated by a semicolon

So your for loop should start out like this:

```
for(int i = 0;i <= 50; i++){ 
    //code here 
}
```

[Official arduino For Loop Reference](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/control-structure/for/)